# ¿Cómo hago para conseguir la siguiente salida en pantalla? JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

> Ejercicio: Haz un programa GenerarPrimos que obtenga los primeros 50
>   números primos mostrando 10 por línea, para ello compruebe si un
>   número es primo (esPrimo).

Lo he realizado así:

```
public class GenerarPrimos {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int numero=0;
            int numerosPrimos=0;
            int linea=0;



            System.out.println("Los primeros 50 numeros primos son");
            System.out.println();

            while(numerosPrimos!=50) {


                if(esPrimo(numero)) {
                    ++numerosPrimos;
                    linea++;
                    System.out.print("  ");
                    System.out.print(numero);
                    if(linea==10) {
                        linea=0;
                        System.out.println();
                    }


                }
            numero++;
        }

    }

    public static boolean esPrimo(int n) {
            int divisor=3;
            //int primo=false;

            if(n==2) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(n==0 || n==1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                while(divisor<n) {


                    if(n %2==0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        if(n%divisor==0) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    divisor+=2;
                }
            }return true;       
        }

}
```

Salida que obtengo:

[image: Salida que obtengo:]

Salida que tengo que obtener:

[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

El problema son los espacios por línea, tienen que ser mayores cuanto menor cifras tenga el numero primo, pero no lo sé bien. He pensado que el método printf quizá pueda arreglarlo, o quizá condicionales que tengan el control sobre las cifras de cada número primo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español! Es una buena primera pregunta, aportando todo lo necesario para ayudarte con tu duda. Te recomiendo de todos modos que completes el [tour] para ganar una segunda medalla y entender cómo funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 7):

Estás en lo cierto. con [System.out.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) puedes hacer algo como

```
if(esPrimo(numero)) {
    ++numerosPrimos;
    linea++;
    System.out.printf("%5d",numero);
    if(linea==10) {
        linea=0;
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Que añadirá espacios a la izquierda para que cada número ocupe 5 caracteres.

Comment: +1 a pesar del error ortográfico aquí `System.out.System.out.printf` seguro de que lo vas a corregir.